# Custom icons inside a .tabItem in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, label, tabview, tabitem

I'm trying to use my custom icons inside all my `.tabItem` elements without any success!

I first tried using a `Label` but the icon is way too big.

```
.tabItem {

    // Label("Home", systemImage: "house.fill")
    Label("Home", image: "home-icon")

}
```

Then, I tried using the combination of an `Image` and a `Text` but the result is the same: the icon is bigger than expected.

```
.tabItem {

    Image("home-icon")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 28, height: 28)

    Text("Home")
        .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
        .foregroundColor(Color("blue"))
        // Test: unfortunately, the font isn't .rounded either!

}
```

Do you guys have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

You missing add method scale for image.

```
 .tabItem {

    Image("home-icon")
        .resizable()
        .scaleToFit()
        .frame(width: 28, height: 28)

    Text("Home")
        .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
        .foregroundColor(Color("blue"))
        // Test: unfortunately, the font isn't .rounded either!

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `scaledToFit()` doesn't change anything at all.

Comment: Could you put it on `ZStack`?